# Google Cloud VPN issue Cisco ASA Cryptomap

Tags: vpn, ipsec, cisco-asa, google

I am trying to set up an IPSec tunnel on a Cisco ASA. In my routes on google, I can see that only 172.0.99.0/24 and 172.0.100.0/24 should be routed through this tunnel.

Google seems to be requesting that all traffic routes through this tunnel

Cisco Logs:

```
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing hash payload
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing SA payload
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing nonce payload
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing ke payload
%ASA-7-713906: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing ISA_KE for PFS in phase 2
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing ID payload
%ASA-7-714011: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, ID_IPV4_ADDR_SUBNET ID received--0.0.0.0--0.0.0.0
%ASA-7-713035: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, Received remote IP Proxy Subnet data in ID Payload:   Address 0.0.0.0, Mask 0.0.0.0, Protocol 0, Port 0
%ASA-7-715047: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, processing ID payload
%ASA-7-714011: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, ID_IPV4_ADDR_SUBNET ID received--0.0.0.0--0.0.0.0
%ASA-7-713034: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, Received local IP Proxy Subnet data in ID Payload:   Address 0.0.0.0, Mask 0.0.0.0, Protocol 0, Port 0
%ASA-7-713906: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, QM IsRekeyed old sa not found by addr
%ASA-7-713221: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = outside_map, seq = 1...
%ASA-7-713222: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, Static Crypto Map check, map = outside_map, seq = 1, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:0.0.0.0 dst:0.0.0.0
%6.243, processing ID payload
%ASA-7-714011: Group = 35.234.136.243, IP = 35.234.136.243, ID_IPV4_ADDR_SUBNET ID received--0.0.0.0--0.0.0.0
```

The google logs show that the connection is established and then the Cisco send a delete when Quickmode is established.

Comment: The encryption domain in GCloud and the ASA do not match:   *ACL does not match proxy IDs src:0.0.0.0 dst:0.0.0.0*.  Please post your Google VPN configuration

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a [Route based tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-route-based-vpns) in GCP which will advertise 0.0.0.0/0 by default as interesting traffic or Encryption domain. I suggest using a [policy based tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-policy-based-vpns) and only advertise 172.0.99.0/24 and 172.0.100.0/24 as needed.